# ¿Cómo transformar fechas de PHP a Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Manejo PHP, pero soy novata en Javascript. No sé muy bien cómo manipular fechas, ya que no encuentro funciones similares a strtotime.
Agradezco ayuda para transformar estas dos fechas y que me expliquen cuál es la mejor forma... Gracias!

`$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($date)));
 $to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date)));`

El formato de las fechas debe ser como este ejemplo:
2017-01-04 16:17:51

Es para una aplicación que realiza un consulta a mysql entre dos fechas, dos días antes y un día antes. Lo que pasa que hay otra parte en Javascript y necesito trabajar con estos formatos de nuevo

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser obligatoriamente `javascript` nativo? Puedes hacerlo con jquery, así: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048204/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-strtotime

Comment: No esta claro cual es el objetivo final. ¿Tienes las fechas en `PHP` y quisieras recuperarlas en `JS`? ¿Cual es el formato de entrada y el de salida? ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de lo que buscas obtener?

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos un contexto de uso para saber cuál sería la manera óptima de hacer lo que deseas? Existen clases en PHP y JavaScript para el trabajo con fechas, pero el código que debes usar depende de varios aspectos de tu código. ¿De dónde obtienes `$date` y para qué quieres usar `$from` y `$to`?

Comment: Si eso es, necesito esas fechas de PHP a JS y es para trabajar con consultas en mysql y comparar esas fechas después, de ahí el formato

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Debes dar mas contexto, por ejemplo, como se interrelaciona PHP con PHP. Estas sirviendo el codigo javascript con PHP, o te comunicas con PHP usando AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes en `PHP`:

```
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($date)));
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date)));
```

Puedes hacer fácilmente esto en tu script embebido:

```
var dateFrom = new Date('<?=$from?>');
var dateTo = new Date('<?=$to?>');
```